# angular2 checkbox value when checked set 1 and unchecked to set 0

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to check value whether 0 or 1 using checked and unchecked

```html
<div class="roadblock"> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_style1" id="roaddiv" [(ngModel)]="note.selected" /> </div>
<div class="roadtext"> Road block </div>
<div class="roadblock"> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_style1" id="devdiv" [(ngModel)]="note.selected" /> </div>
<div class="roadtext"> Deviation </div>
<div class="roadblock"> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_style1" id="changediv" [(ngModel)]="note.selected" /> </div>
<div class="roadtext"> Change in approach</div>
<div class="roadblock"> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_style1" id="techdiv" [(ngModel)]="note.selected" /> </div>
<div class="roadtext"> Tech help</div>
```

Comment: Not a duplicate, AngularJS vs Angular 2+...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use expressions in `ngModel` bindings to translate the values:

```
[ngModel]="note.selected == 1 ? true : note.selected == 0 ? false : null" (ngModelChange)="note.selected = $event ? 1 : 0"
```

but this requires to split `[(ngModel)]` to `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)`

Comment: Why does `$event` work in `note.selected = $event ? 1 : 0`. Why I don't need something like `$event.target.value` ?

Comment: Because `$event` is the event from `ngModel`, not some DOM event from the browser.